# Eclipse Syntax Highlighting Java Struts Hibernate Web App

Tags: java, eclipse, struts2, syntax-highlighting

I am just getting started on **Java, Struts, Hibernate, Tomcat** - based **Web App Development** on Eclipse.

I have installed **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** on my Ubuntu system.

> Do I need to **install any plugins** for **Syntax Highlighting** to work properly - for Forms, Actions, Servlets, Classes, etc.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it should be all included. As long as you include the Struts schema tag on any page that uses any struts tags (s:whatever) it should pick up the syntax automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> EMMERICH: "As long as you include the Struts schema tag on any page that uses any struts tags (s:whatever) it should pick up the syntax automatically."

No, that is not sufficient to make it work.

Try this:

```
    <s:if test="#balance<=0">
    <p>whatever</p>
    </s:if>
```

Because of the < used in the struts tag, Eclipse's syntax highlighting would just fail and warn errors.